# beforeDelete function does not work

Tags: php, yii

There is the following model Task with `beforeDelete` function:

```
public function beforeDelete()
{
    $model=Proposal::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('task_id'=>$this->id));
    $model->updateAll(array('task_id'=>null, 'task_result'=>null));
    parent::beforeDelete();
}
```

As you can see, I'd like to get some records from `Proposal` model (using `task_id` field) and update some fields in sorted records. But this code doesn't work - tasks are deleted from task table without updating the fields in proposal table. How can I fix it?

UPDATED:

```
$model=Proposal::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('task_id'=>$this->id));
foreach ($model as $proposal)
{
    $proposal->task_id=null;
    $proposal->task_result=null;
    $proposal->update();
}
parent::beforeDelete();
```

I've just updated my code, but it doesn't work yet.

Comment: This shouldn't work at all - `findAll` returns an array, not an object, and you're not returning any permission to actually delete the records... Remove the `findAllByAttributes` line and pass the adjusted search condition into `updateAll` as the second argument.

Comment: please, look at updates

Answer (score 2):

You should simply try (no need to use `findAllByAttributes`) :

```
Proposal::model()->updateAll(
    array('task_id'=>null, 'task_result'=>null),
    'task_id=:task_id',
    array(':task_id'=>$this->id)
);
return parent::beforeDelete();
```

As *DCoder* said in its comment, it is the best option.

And as *Kevin Higgins* said in its answer, you should return `parent::beforeDelete()`.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#updateAll-detail

**Or** if you still want to use `findAllByAttributes` :

```
$models = Proposal::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('task_id'=>$this->id));
foreach ($models as $proposal)
{
    $proposal->update(array('task_id'=>null, 'task_result'=>null));
}
return parent::beforeDelete();
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#update-detail

**Or** :

```
$models = Proposal::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('task_id'=>$this->id));
foreach ($models as $proposal)
{
    $proposal->task_id=null;
    $proposal->task_result=null;
    $proposal->save();
}
return parent::beforeDelete();
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#save-detail

Comment: It's worth noting that the first two options are more expensive than the third. 1 query to fetch the records plus N queries to update them, versus just 1 query used in the third case.

Comment: Of course, I should have mentioned this, thanks. Answer updated (re-ordering).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your original deletion code being wrong, you should be returning the result of parent::beforeDelete();

Your code should look like this (using soju's third recommendation):

```
public function beforeDelete()
{
    Proposal::model()->updateAll(
        array('task_id'=>null, 'task_result'=>null),
        'task_id=:task_id',
        array(':task_id'=>$this->id)
    );
    return parent::beforeDelete();
}
```